# Call JS function from another file in VueJS component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm starting doing some stuff in Vue.Js. I have a localStorage.js file added to my html, and there are no problems with the file itself. If I use the browser's console I can call the functions inside of it, no matter which component is loaded in the router-view. I need to render a list of elements in a component, using data that a function inside of my js file returns, but I can't get it to work. How can I use the response from said function as data in my component, so I can loop over it with v-for? The function returns an array of objects. I tried setting up the component like this:

```
export default {
    name: 'lista',
    components: {
        codiceLista
     },
     data(){
       return readLocalStorage()
     }
```

With readLocalStorage being the function in my external file, but it says that it's not defined. Any help would be kindly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply import it:

```js
import { readLocalStorage } from 'external/file/location'; // <- here

export default {
    name: 'lista',
    components: {
        codiceLista
     },
     data(){
       return readLocalStorage()
     },
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this, it doesn't tell me that the function isn't defined anymore, but now, it tells me that data() is not a function, even tho it's strctured like you wrote. (It compiles now, but it's a runtime error). Should I add export in front of the function declaration in the js file?

Comment: This is not valid syntax. You can add it to a property inside of the data but not return the function like you did.
`data() { return { myFunc: readLocalStorage }}`